# Currency Convertor in Python: Code stopping midway

Tags: python, debugging, input, error-handling, currency

I need some help with this issue. I am coding a currency converter in python. However, it stops running midway. Could someone please help me debug? Thank you in advance for your time and effort. Below is my code:

````
print("FOR DOLLARS:   Type 1 for USD to CAD, 2 for CAD to USD, 3 for USD to GBR, 4 for GBR to USD, 5 for USD to INR, 6 for INR to USD")

print("For Canadian currency: Type 7 for CAD to GBR, Type 8 for GBR to CAD,type 9 for CAD to INR and 10 for INR to CAD ")

print("FOR POUNDS(British Currency) type 11 for GBR to INR and 12 for INR to GBR. If you wish to convert for INR, choose appropriate options above")

print("CHOOSE YOUR OPERATION ")
aq=input("Enter choice here:")
qwe=int(input("How much of the currency would you like to convert. "))
print("Give us a minute while we process your request")
if aq==1:
  print("So",qwe," in CAD is approximately", qwe*1.25, "CAD")
if aq==2:
  print("So",qwe,"in USD is approximately ",qwe*0.80,"USD")
if aq==3:
  print("So",qwe,"in GBR is approximately",qwe*0.77,"GBR")
if aq==4:
  print("So",qwe,"in USD is approximately",qwe*1.30,"GBR")
if aq==5:
  print("So",qwe,"in INR is approximately",qwe*76.29,"INR")
if aq==6:
  print("So",qwe,"in USD is approximately",qwe*0.013,"USD")
if aq==7:
  print("So",qwe,"in GBR is approximately", qwe*0.61,"GBR")
if aq==8:
  print("So",qwe,"in CAD is approximately", qwe*1.63,"CAD")
if aq==9:
  print("So",qwe,"in INR is approximately", qwe*60.85,"INR")
if aq==10:
  print("So",qwe,"in CAD is approximately", qwe*0.016,"INR")
if aq==11:
  print("So",qwe,"in INR is approximately", qwe*99.46,"INR")
if aq==12:
  print("So",qwe,"in GBR is approximately", qwe*0.010,"GBR")```
````

Comment: `aq` is a string, it will never be equal to any of the numbers.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much, that really helped, the code works now. Again thank you so much! ~AKJ121